# How to implement a UITabBar view in Mac OS X applications?

Tags: cocoa, macos

In my Mac application I'd like to implement a view that simulates `UITabBar` from iOS.

What's the preferred way to implement this? Use `NSOutlineView` , `NSTableView`, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a native Mac app, the equivalent of a UITabBar is an [NSTabView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTabView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). If you want to go for the iOS look, you either have to roll your own with some NSView subclass or take a look at [UMEKit](http://parsekit.com/umekit/).

[Chameleon](http://chameleonproject.org/) may also be an option, but it currently doesn't implement UITabBar, this might change in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to follow a trend of making your Mac app with the UIKit look-and-feel 
you might want to take a look at the [Chameleon Project](http://chameleonproject.org/) - note the status of the project on the developer's [blog](http://furbo.org/2011/04/19/a-disappointment/). However, the project source is on [github](https://github.com/BigZaphod/Chameleon) now, and people are helping out.